# Moving to the next activity after capturing the picture

Tags: android, android-activity

My app have a post button. When the user click it, the camera will open directly so he can take the picture.

The problem is that when the user capture the picture and click the tick button, the app crashes.

I want to move to the next activity once the user capture the picture

here is my code

```
buttonSortCap.setOnClickListener(new btnTakePhotoClicker());
```

This is the btnTakePhotoClicker class

```
class btnTakePhotoClicker implements Button.OnClickListener{
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(camera, CAM_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

This is the activity to put the image in a Bitmap

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == CAM_REQUEST){
        Bitmap thum = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imgTakenPhoto.setImageBitmap(thum);
    }
    ...
}
```

This is what it shows me in Android Studio

```
4-17 12:49:44.625    2278-2278/com.example.barakah E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.barakah, PID: 2278
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1313, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.barakah/com.example.barakah.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: share your crash log. also where you are starting next activity in your code ?

Comment: Is is NullPointerException on `imgTakenPhoto.setImageBitmap` or the error raises in the line above?

Comment: there is no compile time error. The error occur when i capture the picture.

Comment: There is no compile time error. when i capture the picture it shows me "Unfortunately, AppName has stopped working"

Comment: maybe my problem of how i open the new activity .. isn't it this way - startActionMode((android.view.ActionMode.Callback) new Intent("com.example.barakah.PostActivity"));

Comment: The stack traces shows up in LogCat. Copy and paste it in your question

Comment: I think you are getting null intent. In your case `data`.

Comment: @AryamSaleh see my answer below, did that solved your problem??

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the following - 
`if (requestCode == CAM_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all data intent in this case does not have any extras, you need to call its getData() method. Secondly it returns the uri of the image instead of actual image. Try this code instead:

```
if (requestCode == CAM_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    Uri image_uri = data.getData();
    Bitmap bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), image_uri);
    imgTakenPhoto.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```